# What is the difference between navGraphViewModels and activityViewModels?

Tags: android, android-viewmodel, android-navigation

I know about `SharedViewModel`(`by activityviewModel`) how to share data between ViewModels.

But recently I also learned about `navGraphViewModels`.

I've tried both methods in my code using `Navigation Component`, but there doesn't seem to be much difference.

Both `by activityViewModels` and `by navGraphViewModels` confirmed that the data of screen `B` is maintained even if it is returned to screen `B` after moving to screen `A`.

What is the difference between these two?

---

[image]

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/calendarFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/calendarFragment"
        android:name="com.example.lightweight.presentation.ui.calendar.CalendarFragment"
        android:label="fragment_calendar"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_calendar" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/dailyWorkoutLogFragment"
        android:name="com.example.lightweight.presentation.ui.write.DailyWorkoutLogFragment"
        android:label="fragment_daily_workout_log"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_daily_workout_log" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_dailyWorkoutLogFragment_to_navigation"
            app:destination="@id/navigation" />
    </fragment>
    <navigation android:id="@+id/navigation"
        app:startDestination="@id/addRoutine">
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/workoutListTabFragment"
            android:name="com.example.lightweight.presentation.ui.write.WorkoutListTabFragment"
            android:label="WorkoutListTabFragment"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_workout_list_tab">
            <action
                android:id="@+id/action_workoutListTabFragment_to_writeDetailFragment"
                app:destination="@id/writeDetailFragment" />
        </fragment>
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/writeDetailFragment"
            android:name="com.example.lightweight.presentation.ui.write.WriteDetailFragment"
            android:label="fragment_write_detail"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_write_detail">
            <argument
                android:name="workout"
                android:defaultValue="@null"
                app:argType="string"
                app:nullable="true" />
            <action
                android:id="@+id/action_writeDetailFragment_to_addRoutine"
                app:destination="@id/addRoutine" />
        </fragment>
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/addRoutine"
            android:name="com.example.lightweight.presentation.ui.write.AddRoutineFragment"
            android:label="fragment_add_routine"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_add_routine">

            <action
                android:id="@+id/action_addRoutine_to_workoutListTabFragment"
                app:destination="@id/workoutListTabFragment" />
        </fragment>
    </navigation>
</navigation>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`activityViewModels()` returns the view Model which is Scoped to Activity .
Thats means all the Child fragments of this `Activity` will be sharing the same Instance of `ViewModel` when created by  `activityViewModels()`.

When created by `navGraphViewModels()` the  ViewModel is Scoped to  navigation graph . it accepts a `navGraphId: @IdRes Int` of Subgraph . this is helpful When you do not want to Share  Viewmodel b/w all the fragments and just b/w fragments of certain module for example Login/register.

In single Activity Architecture You might want a `ViewModel`  scoped to SignIn/SignUp graph but not for all other screens . in this case you can use `navGraphViewModels` with Sub-graph id and Share same instance only b/w the component of that graph only.

If you have a single Graph and use root as `navGraphId` for `navGraphViewModels` then both `navGraphViewModels()` and `activityViewModels()` will end up having same scope.

Comment: I'm sorry, but what is `b/w`..between?

Anyway, you mean that `activityViewModels()` keeps the Fragment's ViewModel data from start to finish, and `navGraphViewModels()` means that data is destroyed when it goes out of scope of the `nav_graph` or `Sub_graph(probably nested_graph?)`?

Comment: Yeah thats what Scope means . Activity Scope means as long as Activity lives (Including config changes case i.e ViewModelScope) .

Comment: great. But will the scope of `navGraphViewModels()` be `nav_graph` or `nested_graph` inside nav_graph?

Comment: You will use it for nested graph that's where it comes in handy ..