# Navigation component - Why ViewModel is not re-created even though its owner (Fragment) is being re-created in NavHostFragment?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewmodel, android-navigation, android-navhostfragment

I am referring to the **Bottom Navigation Views Activity** template project created by Android Studio.

I notice, whenever I tap on the bottom view to switch from `DashboardFragment` page, to another fragment page. Then, I tap on the bottom view again to switch back to `DashboardFragment`, a new `DashboardFragment` will be constructed.

I have verified such a behaviour by having logging in its `init` function.

### DashboardFragment.kt

```
class DashboardFragment : Fragment() {

    ...

    init {
        Log.i("CHEOK", "DashboardFragment constructed")
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        Log.i("CHEOK", "ViewModelProvider(this).get in DashboardFragment onCreateView")

        val dashboardViewModel =
            ViewModelProvider(this).get(DashboardViewModel::class.java)
```

### DashboardViewModel.kt

```
class DashboardViewModel : ViewModel() {

    ...

    init {
        Log.i("CHEOK", "DashboardViewModel constructed")
    }
}
```

---

However, to my surprise, `DashboardViewModel`, which is a `DashboardFragment` owned `ViewModel`, is not being re-constructed.

---

Here's is the logging I am observing, when `DashboardFragment` is switched to visible for the **1st time**.

> DashboardFragment constructed
>
> ViewModelProvider(this).get in DashboardFragment onCreateView
>
> DashboardViewModel constructed

When I switch to another fragment, and then switch back to `DashboardFragment` for the **2nd time**, the following is the logging I am observing

> DashboardFragment constructed
>
> ViewModelProvider(this).get in DashboardFragment onCreateView

I am expecting `DashboardViewModel` will be re-created again. This is because, `ViewModelProvider` is having `DashboardFragment` as its owner, and not `MainActivity`.

```
val dashboardViewModel =
            ViewModelProvider(this).get(DashboardViewModel::class.java)
```

When the 1st `DashboardFragment` is destroyed, the `DashboardViewModel` should be destroyed too. But, seems like this is not the case.

May I know, why `ViewModel` is not re-created even though its owner (Fragment) is being re-created in `NavHostFragment`?

### Demo

You may test the demo at https://github.com/yccheok/lifecycle-NavHostFragment/tree/f58b7aa6773de09811e9858a84a3b4614edbe3b3

Comment: it is because of https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:navigation/navigation-fragment/src/main/java/androidx/navigation/fragment/FragmentNavigator.kt;l=325?q=shouldRestoreState&start=11

Comment: This is the intended purpose and behavior of ViewModelProvider. Why do you have the expectation that it would behave differently? If you want to have a class that is constructed every time your Fragment is constructed, don't use ViewModelProvider for it.

Comment: Hi, I do not expect ViewModelProvider behave in such a way. Based on my usage experience (Without using Navigation component), if we associate ViewModelProvider with an Activity (Using `ViewModelProvider(activity)`), it will retain always, even the fragment is destroyed and created again. However, if the ViewModelProvider is associated with a Fragment (Using `ViewModelProvider(this)`), it should destroyed completely, if the fragment is destroyed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on [Arda Kazancı](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76451515/6309)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76451515/6309), the [back stack](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-training-navigation-backstack#3) is a record of the navigation history within a `NavController`.
Each time you navigate to a [`Fragment`](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments), that `Fragment` is added to the back stack.
When you navigate back, the current `Fragment` is popped off the back stack, and the previous `Fragment` is recreated.

However, if you are scoping your [`ViewModel`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel) to the [`NavController`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/NavController)'s lifecycle, the `ViewModel` will not be recreated along with the `Fragment`; instead, the existing `ViewModel` instance will be reused.

When we talk about scoping a `ViewModel` to a `Fragment`'s lifecycle or to a `NavController`'s lifecycle, we are talking about when the `ViewModel` is created and destroyed.

- If the `ViewModel` is scoped to the `Fragment`'s lifecycle (using `viewLifecycleOwner`), the `ViewModel` will be created when the `Fragment`'s view is created and destroyed when the `Fragment`'s view is destroyed. This is true whether the `Fragment` is destroyed because it was popped off the back stack or because of a configuration change like a screen rotation.
- If the `ViewModel` is scoped to the `NavController`'s lifecycle (the default behavior when using `ViewModelProvider(this)` in a `Fragment`), the `ViewModel` will be created the first time the `Fragment` is launched and will not be destroyed until the `NavController` is destroyed (which usually happens when the activity hosting the `NavController` is finished). This means that the `ViewModel` will survive even if the `Fragment` is destroyed and recreated, such as when the user navigates away from the `Fragment` and then back to it, causing the `Fragment` to be popped off the back stack and then added back to it.

When you are using the Navigation component along with [`NavHostFragment`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/fragment/NavHostFragment), it uses a slightly different lifecycle scope for the `ViewModel` than a standalone `Fragment` would. In other words, even though your `Fragment` is being recreated, the associated `ViewModel` is not.

(See also "[Get started with the Navigation component](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/get-started)")

This is because `NavHostFragment` maintains its own [`ViewModelStore`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/ViewModelStore) that is scoped to the `NavController`'s lifecycle. This `ViewModelStore` is used to store `ViewModels` for all destinations (fragments) that are a part of the `NavController`.

(See also "[Communication of Fragments in the Fragment, using Navigation Component, MVVM and Koin](https://medium.com/schibsted-tech-polska/communication-of-fragments-in-the-fragment-using-navigation-component-mvvm-and-koin-ca9a70bf001b)" by [Piotr Prus](https://pt.linkedin.com/in/piotrprus))

When you are calling `ViewModelProvider(this).get(DashboardViewModel::class.java)`, the `ViewModel` is being retrieved from the `ViewModelStore` associated with the `NavController`, not the individual fragment. This means that the `ViewModel` will persist as long as the `NavController` is alive, even if individual fragments are destroyed and recreated.

This design allows data to be persisted across configuration changes and navigation events, which is a common pattern in Android development.

You can observe this behavior by checking the ID of the `ViewModel` object:

```kotlin
Log.i("CHEOK", "DashboardViewModel constructed. ID: ${System.identityHashCode(this)}")
```

You will see that the ID remains the same across different instances of the `Fragment`, indicating that it is the same `ViewModel` instance.

---

If you want a `ViewModel` that is scoped to the `NavController`'s lifecycle and survives configuration changes and navigation between `Fragments`, you can use [`navGraphViewModels`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/navigation/package-summary#(androidx.fragment.app.Fragment).navGraphViewModels(kotlin.Int,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Function0)):

```kotlin
class DashboardFragment : Fragment() {

    private val dashboardViewModel: DashboardViewModel by navGraphViewModels(R.id.nav_graph) { ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory.getInstance(activity?.application!!) }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        // Use the ViewModel
    }
}
```

Here, `R.id.nav_graph` is the ID of your navigation graph. This `ViewModel` will be shared between all `Fragments` in the navigation graph and will be destroyed when the last `Fragment` in the navigation graph is popped off the back stack.

(See also "[What is the difference between navGraphViewModels and activityViewModels?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73891960/6309)")

But then, the original behavior you observed will persist. The `DashboardViewModel` will not be re-constructed each time you navigate back to the `DashboardFragment`.

The `navGraphViewModels` delegate method creates or retrieves a `ViewModel` that is scoped to a navigation graph. This means the `ViewModel` will be shared between all fragments in the navigation graph and will survive configuration changes and navigation between fragments. The `ViewModel` will only be cleared (and thus ready for re-construction) when the last fragment in the navigation graph is popped off the back stack.

---

If you want the `ViewModel` to be scoped to the `Fragment`'s lifecycle instead of the `NavController`'s lifecycle, you would have to use the `ViewModelProvider` with the `Fragment`'s `viewLifecycleOwner`:

```kotlin
val dashboardViewModel = ViewModelProvider(viewLifecycleOwner).get(DashboardViewModel::class.java)
```

Note: as noted in "[ViewModelProviders is deprecated in 1.1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53903865/6309)", early in 2020, Google had deprecated the ViewModelProviders class, in version 2.2.0 of the [AndroidX lifecycle library](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle).

In the context of the AndroidX libraries, the equivalent would be:

```kotlin
dashboardViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory.getInstance(activity?.application!!)).get(DashboardViewModel::class.java)
```

With `this` referring to the `Fragment` itself. `ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory.getInstance(activity?.application!!)` is the `Factory` that is used to create the `ViewModel`. This factory requires the `Application` as a parameter, and it is retrieved from the `Fragment`'s associated `Activity`.

Those codes will give you a `ViewModel` that is scoped to the `Fragment`'s lifecycle and will be recreated every time the `Fragment` is recreated.
However, keep in mind that this might not be the desired behavior, especially if you want to maintain state across navigation events.

Illustration: "[**How Android ViewModel works under the hood to survive to configuration change**](https://proandroiddev.com/how-viewmodel-works-under-the-hood-52a4f1ff64cf)" by [Torcheux Frédéric](https://twitter.com/bowser_f).

Answer (score 0):

Because Dashboard Fragment is located in back stack. It has been created at least once. It includes the concept of **Multiple** BackStacks.

In some cases, your app might need to support multiple back stacks. A common example is if your app uses a bottom navigation bar. FragmentManager lets you support multiple back stacks with the **saveBackStack()** and **restoreBackStack()** methods. These methods let you swap between back stacks by saving one back stack and restoring a different one.